# Get text of value of node inside SOAP body if node changes

Tags: xpath

I have a SOAP request like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.revenue.ie/ras/webservices">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">BWyAGdlqp5ZuySEwHUfniA==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-07-24T09:43:16.665Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <thisNodeChanges>
 <string   xsi:type="xsd:string">DATAHERE</string>
</thisNodeChanges>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can i get the text value "DATAHERE" with xpath if "thisNodeChanges" changes from request to request and so does "string".

If i do `//string/text()`it works but it's not always called string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
'//*[name()="soapenv:Body"]/*/*/text()'
```